# Multiwire Branch circuit and ground

Tags: grounding

[image]I have a multiwire beach circuit which feeds the furnace and the laundry area.  At the junction box where the neutrals are tied together, what do I do with the ground wires from each circuit (furnace & laundry)?  Are they tied together?  Not used?

Comment: Post a pic of the inside of the junction box.

Answer (score 9):

### Tie them all together and to the box

Grounding conductors are always tied together at every box; since you have a metal box, you need to provide a grounding pigtail to the box as well.

Comment: OP needs to find a ground screw. It should be a 10-32 machine screw with a hex or round head.

Comment: @RibaldEddie -- yeah, they can just get the pre-made grounding pigtails and put one in the correct size hole tho :)